# Incorrect Maquest Direction Route API Feedback

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, mapquest

I am integrating the [MapQuest API Direction Routing function](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/directions-api/route/post/) into my website. However, when I submit my request to the API, it returns incorrect routing points between 2 destinations.

Below is the request form I POST to the API: `http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v2/route?key=[APIKEY]`

```
   {
        "locations": [
                {
                    "latLng": {
                        "lat":  37.47601247,
                        "lng": 126.96594338
                    }
                },
                {
                    "latLng": {
                        "lat": 37.4713402954355,
                        "lng": 126.95234849232048
                    }
                }
        ],
        "options": {
            "avoids": [],
            "avoidTimedConditions": false,
            "doReverseGeocode": false,
            "enhancedNarrative": true,
            "generalize": 0,
            "narrativeType": "text",
            "routeType": "fastest",
            "shapeFormat": "raw",
            "unit": "k"
        }
    }
```

And the results that I received, I used the `startPoint.lng` and `startPoint.lat` in the `maneuvers`, but that doesn't seem to be correct

Below is the return results and map illustrations:

```
{
    "route": {
        "sessionId": "AHEA5gcAAFMBAAANAAAAMgAAAIQAAAB42mNoYWBgZGJgYGDPSC1KtUrOfcOaA-IybLykdYbrcqHnrSM-y6L8v3nd4t63PIoBC0DXeI7hyGImxx9ut9iLl0YdZPO69S5mBVaNILAwZvIzEA0AW5Egkyj61e4:car",
        "realTime": 31,
        "distance": 0.6,
        "time": 31,
        "formattedTime": "00:00:31",
        "hasHighway": false,
        "hasTollRoad": false,
        "hasBridge": false,
        "hasSeasonalClosure": false,
        "hasTunnel": false,
        "hasFerry": false,
        "hasUnpaved": false,
        "hasTimedRestriction": false,
        "hasCountryCross": false,
        "shape": {
            "shapePoints": [
                37.483936,
                126.974279,
                37.48681,
                126.96995,
                37.487346,
                126.969139
            ],
            "legIndexes": [
                0,
                3
            ],
            "maneuverIndexes": [
                0,
                2
            ]
        },
        "legs": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "hasTollRoad": false,
                "hasHighway": false,
                "hasBridge": false,
                "hasUnpaved": false,
                "hasTunnel": false,
                "hasSeasonalClosure": false,
                "hasFerry": false,
                "hasCountryCross": false,
                "hasTimedRestriction": false,
                "distance": 0.6,
                "time": 31,
                "formattedTime": "00:00:31",
                "origIndex": 0,
                "origNarrative": "",
                "destIndex": 0,
                "destNarrative": "",
                "maneuvers": [
                    {
                        "index": 0,
                        "distance": 0.6,
                        "narrative": "Head northwest. Go for 591 m.",
                        "time": 31,
                        "direction": 2,
                        "directionName": "Northwest",
                        "signs": [],
                        "maneuverNotes": [],
                        "formattedTime": "00:00:31",
                        "transportMode": "car",
                        "startPoint": {
                            "lng": 126.974279,
                            "lat": 37.483936
                        },
                        "turnType": 0,
                        "mapUrl": "",
                        "attributes": 0,
                        "iconUrl": "",
                        "streets": []
                    },
                    {
                        "index": 1,
                        "distance": 0,
                        "narrative": "Arrive at your destination.",
                        "time": 0,
                        "direction": 0,
                        "directionName": "None",
                        "signs": [],
                        "maneuverNotes": [],
                        "formattedTime": "00:00:00",
                        "transportMode": "car",
                        "startPoint": {
                            "lng": 126.969139,
                            "lat": 37.487345999999995
                        },
                        "turnType": 0,
                        "mapUrl": "",
                        "attributes": 0,
                        "iconUrl": "",
                        "streets": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "options": {
            "avoids": [],
            "avoidTimedConditions": false,
            "doReverseGeocode": false,
            "enhancedNarrative": true,
            "generalize": 2,
            "narrativeType": "text",
            "routeType": "FASTEST",
            "shapeFormat": "raw",
            "unit": "K",
            "walkingSpeed": -1,
            "highwayEfficiency": 22,
            "locale": "en_US",
            "useTraffic": false,
            "timeType": 0,
            "dateType": 0,
            "sideOfStreetDisplay": true
        },
        "boundingBox": {
            "ul": {
                "lng": 126.969139,
                "lat": 37.487345999999995
            },
            "lr": {
                "lng": 126.974279,
                "lat": 37.483936
            }
        },
        "routeWarnings": [],
        "maxRoutes": "",
        "locations": [
            {
                "street": "",
                "adminArea6": "",
                "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood",
                "adminArea5": "",
                "adminArea5Type": "City",
                "adminArea4": "",
                "adminArea4Type": "County",
                "adminArea3": "",
                "adminArea3Type": "State",
                "adminArea1": "",
                "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                "postalCode": "",
                "geocodeQualityCode": "XXXXX",
                "geocodeQuality": "LATLNG",
                "dragPoint": false,
                "sideOfStreet": "N",
                "linkId": "0",
                "unknownInput": "",
                "type": "s",
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 37.47601247,
                    "lng": 126.96594338
                },
                "displayLatLng": {
                    "lat": 37.47601247,
                    "lng": 126.96594338
                }
            },
            {
                "street": "",
                "adminArea6": "",
                "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood",
                "adminArea5": "",
                "adminArea5Type": "City",
                "adminArea4": "",
                "adminArea4Type": "County",
                "adminArea3": "",
                "adminArea3Type": "State",
                "adminArea1": "",
                "adminArea1Type": "Country",
                "postalCode": "",
                "geocodeQualityCode": "XXXXX",
                "geocodeQuality": "LATLNG",
                "dragPoint": false,
                "sideOfStreet": "N",
                "linkId": "0",
                "unknownInput": "",
                "type": "s",
                "latLng": {
                    "lat": 37.4713402954355,
                    "lng": 126.95234849232048
                },
                "displayLatLng": {
                    "lat": 37.4713402954355,
                    "lng": 126.95234849232048
                }
            }
        ],
        "locationSequence": [
            0,
            1
        ]
    },
    "info": {
        "statuscode": 0,
        "copyright": {
            "text": "© 2022 MapQuest, Inc.",
            "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
            "imageAltText": "© 2022 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
        "messages": []
    }
}
```

[image: Incorrect Routing!]

Are there any parameters I have to adjust to archive the correct information? I have tried to change `generalize` parameter but it does not help much. I used to get the location really precise about a month ago... This is strange to me

[image: Demostration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapQuest's map/route data in South Korea is lacking a lot of detail. We hope some day to have more detailed routing in the area.

Comment: but the problem is... I used to get the correct routing from MapQuest in Korea

Comment: The data provider in that area changed and there is less data there now, unfortunately.

Comment: The MapQuest team is working on getting better geocode, route, and map data. We hope to have more detail soon.